# How to run a code through each column (containing information) within excel?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, repeat

I'm working on a document where I need to remove duplicate values from several hundreds of columns independently of one another.  My data begins in column H. I know I can use

```
Range("H1:H100").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
```

to do it on that column, but is there a way to start with H and then run that code on every column which contains data?

I've searched extensively on this issue and haven't been able to find code that successfully does what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following code, the variable `c` starts at `8` because you have said your code needs to run from column `H` - you can change this to suit.

```
Option Explicit
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
Dim c As Long, LastCol as Long
LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For c = 8 To LastCol
    If Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row <> 1 Then
        Cells(1, c).EntireColumn.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this did the trick perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty basic, something like this should do the trick:

```
For Each Rng In ReplaceRng.Columns(1).Cells
    InputRng.replace what:=Rng.Value, replacement:=Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value, Lookat:=xlPart
Next
```

Comment: I don't follow, where does ReplaceRng.Columns(1).Cells come from? and InputRng?